# Putting Scrolling Feature Into Second Frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI in Tkinter where a user can click on a card, have the card appear in a frame called "DiscardFrame", and then scroll through the frame if many cards have been added to it.

Each card displayed in the frame called "MeldFrame" is a button represented as a card image.

The following is my program:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
MainWindow = Tk()
MainWindow.config(bg="green")
MainWindow.geometry("1350x680")
MainWindow.title("Canasta")


class Card:
    def __init__(self, cardText):
        self.__cardText = cardText

    def GetCardText(self):
        return self.__cardText


def DisplayMeld(Meld, rowNo, meldNo, verticalPos, MeldFrame):
    if len(Meld) > 0:
        columnNo = 0

        firstColumnFilled = False
        noOfCardsInRow = 0

        for card in Meld:
            if firstColumnFilled == False:
                Label(MeldFrame, text="                                       ", bg="green").grid(
                    row=rowNo, column=columnNo)
                firstColumnFilled = True
            columnNo += 1

            if noOfCardsInRow == 5:
                rowNo += 1
                columnNo = 1
                verticalPos += 215
                noOfCardsInRow = 0

            Button(MeldFrame, text=card.GetCardText(), command=lambda: AddCard(card)).grid(
                row=rowNo, column=columnNo, padx=(10, 0), pady=(0, 10))

            noOfCardsInRow += 1

        rowNoAndVerticalPos = [rowNo, verticalPos]
        return rowNoAndVerticalPos


def PrintCard(cardText, cardToDiscardVar):
    cardToDiscardVar.set(cardText)
    print("cardToDiscardVar:", cardToDiscardVar.get())


RoundFrame = Frame(MainWindow, bg="green")
RoundFrame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

canvas = Canvas(RoundFrame, bg="green")

canvas2 = Canvas(RoundFrame, bg="green")

MeldFrame = Frame(canvas, bg="green")

canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# anchor="nw" means anchor the canvas to the top left corner.
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=MeldFrame, anchor="nw")

canvas2.pack(side=LEFT)

DiscardFrame = Frame(canvas2, bg="white")

canvas2.create_window((0, 0), window=DiscardFrame, anchor="ne")

CardsBeingMelded = []


def RemoveCard(cardToRemove):
    for card in CardsBeingMelded:
        if card.GetCardText() == cardToRemove.GetCardText():
            CardsBeingMelded.remove(card)
            break


def AddCard(card):
    CardsBeingMelded.append(card)

    # Add the card to the potential meld frame.
    Button(DiscardFrame, text=card.GetCardText(),
           command=RemoveCard(card)).grid()


redThree = Card("3H")

scrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(RoundFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

scrollBar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(RoundFrame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas2.yview)
scrollBar2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(
    scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

canvas2.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollBar2.set)
canvas2.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas2.configure(
    scrollregion=canvas2.bbox("all")))

Meld = [redThree]

Melds = [Meld, Meld, Meld]

meldFormedMsg = Label(RoundFrame, text="The computer formed the following melds:", font=(
    'Helvetica 18 bold'), bg="green")
meldFormedMsg.place(x=170, y=25)

Label(MeldFrame, text="                             ",
      bg="green").grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(0, 40))

Label(RoundFrame, text="                  Potential Meld", font=(
    'Helvetica 18 bold'), bg="green").place(x=820, y=25)

rowNo = 1
verticalPos = 60
meldNo = 1

DiscardFrame.pack(side=TOP, padx=(730, 0), pady=(55, 0))

i = 0

for Meld in Melds:
    rowNoAndVerticalPos = DisplayMeld(
        Meld, rowNo, meldNo, verticalPos, MeldFrame)

    rowNo += 1
    i += 1

    returnedRowNo = rowNoAndVerticalPos[0]
    returnedVerticalPos = rowNoAndVerticalPos[1]

    rowNo = returnedRowNo + 1
    verticalPos = returnedVerticalPos + 215
    meldNo += 1

Button(DiscardFrame, text="Create Meld", font=(
    'Helvetica 18 bold')).grid(row=2)

MainWindow.wait_window(DiscardFrame)

MainWindow.mainloop()
```

Please help me understand how I can add a scroll bar to the "DiscardFrame".

The following is what I currently see when multiple cards are added under "Potential Meld" on the top right corner of the window:

[Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYYNa.png)

I tried to create a second canvas called "canvas2" and then added a scroll bar to it.

I was expecting that I would be able to scroll through the multiple cards seen under the "Potential Meld" label in the top right corner of the window. These cards are in the "DiscardFrame" and I want to scroll through them.

Comment: Post a [mre]. It's too long and cannot be run without image files. Anyway, you didn't make the ```canvas2.yview()``` is called.

Comment: Yes. I have added that to canvas2, but it is still not working. I have updated the code. Please run when you get a chance.

Comment: Research more on Tkinter layouts. And start with a simple unit test module and add more widgets. See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/relent95/6d977a39da9722adbfa7e34d3d3eed35) for an example of a scrolled canvas.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. I appreciate it and will look into recreating it.

Comment: If **frame.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky='nswe')** cannot be used, then I have deduced that **frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)** can be used instead to achieve the same result.